# R's magick package saves animated gifs as looping forever

Tags: r, imagemagick

I have a pre-existing animated gif that loops once. If I read and write it with `library(magick)` the resulting animated gif loops forever.

How do I get the saved animated gif to loop once, just like the original?

[ani.gif](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3xbxs7qhglu74kf/ani.gif?dl=0)

```
library(magick)

img <- image_read("ani.gif")
image_write(img, path = "ani2.gif", format = "gif")
```

Comment: You need to set the loop argument before writing the output. Sorry, I do not know RMagick. In ImageMagick it is -loop X or 0 if you want it to loop without stopping.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this in the command line to make this give loop only once... 0 would mean loop forever.

```
convert -loop 1 ani.gif ani.gif
```

Comment: How do you do that in R?